# Azure DevOps setting source control checkin permission by filetype

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible within Azure Devops source control to block the checking in of certain file types? 
For example, to stop PowerBi (*.pbix) files from being checked in?

Or even better for certain file types enforce additional auditing: (E.g. recording the checking in user has removed personal data contained within file)

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC?

Comment: Currently a mix of both depending on project. But if one enables the above, through the devops interface, would be happy with an answer for that.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Azure DevOps setting source control checkin permission by filetype

AFAIK, there is no such check-in permission settings to block the checking in of certain file types on Azure Devops **interface**.

On the web portal, we always edit the file `.gitignore` or `.tfignore` directly to prevent check-in of certain file types.

Besides, if you are using TFVC, there is a option `Check-In Policies` on the Visual Studio, which also can be used to add check-in policy requirements to prevent to check file into the source control by file type.

See the [Enable and Disable Check-In Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/enable-disable-check-policies?view=azure-devops) for some more details.

Hope this helps.